Periodic solutions of differential equation
Prove that the differential equation below has no periodic solutions:
$$  f(x,y,y',y'') = {y''} + 3y' + \big(\sin^{4}(x)-2\big)y = 0$$
I started with $-2 \le \sin^{4}(x)-2 \le -1$ and took a look at the equations:
$ f_1(x,y,y',y'')= {y''} + 3y' -2y = 0$ and   $ f_2(x,y,y',y'')= {y''} + 3y'  -y = 0$.
Those have exponential solutions. I thought that if $f_1(x,y,y',y'')\le f(x,y,y',y'')\le f_2(x,y,y',y'')$ then maybe $f$ have exponential solutions too. Is it right and if it is, how to prove it?
Edit: My mistake in line $f_1(x,y,y',y'')\le f(x,y,y',y'')\le f_2(x,y,y',y'')$. My new question is if we know that $f_1 = 0$ and $f_2 = 0$ have exponential solutions, do $f$ must have exponential solution?

First of all,  it should be $f(x,y,y',y'')$ because the differential equation has a $y$ in it as well as $y'$ and $y''$.  Second, it's certainly not true that $f_1 \le f \le f_2$ in general: in fact $f_1 \le f \le f_2$ if $y \ge 0$ but not if $y < 0$.

Sorry, I will fix it.

The constant $y=0$ is technically a periodic solution, but I'm assuming you're excluding that from consideration.
Suppose $y$ is a periodic solution of your equation that is not identically $0$, and thus (by uniqueness theorem) $y$ and $y'$ are never both $0$. Consider the motion of the point $(y, y')$ in the plane (to avoid confusion with $x$ and $y$, I'll call the coordinates in this plane $X$ and $Y$).
By Rolle's theorem there is some $x_1$ such that $y'(x_1) = 0$.
WLOG (since $-y$ is a solution if $y$ is) we may assume $y(x_0) > 0$.  Then $y''(x_0) = (2 - \sin^4(x_0)) y(x_0) > 0$, so $y'$ is increasing at $x = x_0$.  Thus whenever $(y, y')$ crosses the positive $X$ axis, it does so in an upward direction and enters the first quadrant of the $XY$ plane.  But in that quadrant, $y' > 0$, meaning that $y$ is increasing.  Thus it is impossible for $(y, y')$ to leave the first quadrant, thus impossible to have $y'(x) = 0$ with $x > x_0$, and in particular there can be no
periodic solution other than $y=0$.
